# App crashes on accessing first static variable in class

Tags: ios, swift, static-members

I'm building an iPhone app using Swift. I've created a Settings class and declared some static variables in them, for storing colors. However, whenever I try to access the first variable I've declared (such as Settings.grayBorderColor below), the app crashes (with some message about Settings.grayBorderColor.unsafeMutableAddressor). I can access any properties below the first one just fine, and if I switch the order of the properties/variables, it is still accessing whichever property is declared first that causes the crash.

```
class Settings {

    // MARK: Properties

    static let grayBorderColor = UIColor(red: 0.76, green: 0.76, blue: 0.76, alpha: 1.0)
    static let lightGreenColor = UIColor(red: 0.66, green: 1.0, blue: 0.66, alpha: 1.0)
    static let darkGreenColor = UIColor(red: 0.66, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    static let darkRedColor = UIColor(red: 0.66, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    static let lightRedColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.66, blue: 0.66, alpha: 1.0)
    static let lightGrayColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    static let mediumGrayColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try to rename the first one?

Comment: It still crashes if I rename it. What I meant is, if for example I change darkGreenColor  to the first variable/property, then Settings.darkGreenColor causes the crash instead of settings.grayBorderColor. It seems whatever property is first always crashes.

Comment: Maybe it is a bug in Xcode, your code right.

Comment: Post the full error that Xcode throws

Comment: There isn't really an error, it just crashes and says "(lldb)". But under the Thread list, the first item is: "0 Settings.grayBorderColor.unsafeMutableAddressor"

Comment: It's a weird problem. Did you try changing class settings to struct settings. If you only need this class for settings such as you mentioned than you might as well just make it a struct. Maybe that fixes it

Comment: Thanks for the tip... tried changing it to a struct, but getting the same crash behavior unfortunately.

Comment: Did you find the fix? I am getting the same `unsafeMutableAddressor` crash log from _Crashlytics_, but I am not able to repro. Can you provide your demo code which crashes? Here's my question if you can provide any hint [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37732916/ios-swift-unsafemutableaddressor-crash-on-ios-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37732916/ios-swift-unsafemutableaddressor-crash-on-ios-8)

Comment: I encounter this problem too. But it did not happen before with the same codes. It's a very strange crash.

Answer (score -4):

Change your code to this:

```
class Settings {

    // MARK: Properties

    static let grayBorderColor: UIColor! = UIColor(red: 0.76, green: 0.76, blue: 0.76, alpha: 1.0)
    static let lightGreenColor: UIColor! = UIColor(red: 0.66, green: 1.0, blue: 0.66, alpha: 1.0)
    static let darkGreenColor: UIColor! = UIColor(red: 0.66, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    static let darkRedColor: UIColor! = UIColor(red: 0.66, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    static let lightRedColor: UIColor! = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.66, blue: 0.66, alpha: 1.0)
    static let lightGrayColor: UIColor! = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    static let mediumGrayColor: UIColor! = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

}
```

You were missing property types. As stated in the documentation, calculated properties should have type specifier.

Comment: Did you try changing let to var?

Comment: These aren't calculated properties, they're stored properties. Type specifier not needed.